# Simple parameter passing from controller to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I can't seem to pass a variable all the way from the router to the view. Here's my attempt:

In the router:

```
get '/show/:handle' => 'users#show'
```

In the controller:

```
def show
  @username = params[:handle]
end
```

In the view:

```
<p>A <%= @username %> B</p>
```

Expected result (url "localhost:3000/users/Alex") :

```
<p>A Alex B</p>
```

Actual source (url "localhost:3000/users/Alex") :

```
<p>A  B</p>
```

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the route to `/show/:handle` then you have to use that url ("localhost:3000/show/Alex") and it will work as you expected.

You can read more about Rails routing in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: Thanks, yes I meant for the route to map '/users/:handle'